# Exclude specific site from using TOR

Tags: website

Is it possible to exclude specific site from TOR connection? Like if i want to exclude only google from TOR.

Answer (score 1):

Yes... Two ways.

1. Since on most installs, only the TorBrowser goes through Tor, just open google in chrome.
2. If you don't like [1] you could install FoxyProxy and configure a rule to bypass the Tor Proxy (127.0.0.1:9050) when connected to https://*.google.com
3. Just use duckduckgo since it works with Tor anyway.

My opinion is that [1] is far better than [2], since [2] fingerprints your Tor instance which will go a step towards de-anonomizing you.  Unless your running Tails or Whonix your OS is already sending multiple TCP/UDP connections out while your on Tor anyway.  It is just hard to impossible for most to correlate the traffic.

Best bet would be to use [3].